# Change image background color for woocommerce variation products. This works, but there's over 80 different colors any suggestions to make it faster

Tags: performance

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form', 'switch_image_background_variable_colors' );

function switch_image_background_variable_colors() {

wc_enqueue_js( "

```
  $('input.variation_id').change(function(){
     if('' != $('input.variation_id').val()) {
        if($('#pa_color-631').val() =='white-010'){
           $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
        } else if($('#pa_color-631').val() =='signal-yellow-019'){
           $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', '#E6A925');
        } else if($('#pa_color-631').val() =='golden-yellow-020'){
           $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', '#FCAA19');
        } else if($('#pa_color-631').val() =='yellow-021'){
           $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', '#FDC60C');
        } else if($('#pa_color-631').val() =='light-yellow-022'){
           $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', '#F2CA16');
        } else if($('#pa_color-631').val() =='brimstone-yellow-025'){
           $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', '#F2E20A');
        } else if($('#pa_color-631').val() =='purple-red-026'){
           $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', '#5C0911');
        } else if($('#pa_color-631').val() =='dark-red-030'){
           $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', '#911A1B');
        } else if($('#pa_color-631').val() =='red-031'){
           $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', '#B02025');
        } else if($('#pa_color-631').val() =='light-red-032'){
           $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', '#C82127');
        } else if($('#pa_color-631').val() =='orange-034'){
           $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', '#DD4D25');
        } else if($('#pa_color-631').val() =='pastel-orange-035'){
           $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', '#F46F23');
        } else if($('#pa_color-631').val() =='light-orange-036'){
           $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', '#E86924');
        } 
     } else {
        $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', 'transparent');
     }
  });
```

");

}

Comment: Format the code snippet and add a bit more details to the problem you are having and the solution you are looking for.

Comment: As I'm adding more colors to the snippet, it is getting slower at changing the background color. And in the end there will be 86 colors in total. Anyone that has an idea to change it to make it work faster.

Comment: Try using a object like a dictionary: `{"white-010":"#FFFFFF",...}` if the val() is found in the dictionary, then use the value from the key:value pair in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Each `if()` is a decision to make, but using a dictionary reduces the time it takes to find a match.

try using a dictionary:

```js
const colorsDict = {
  "white-010":"#FFFFFF",
  "signal-yellow-019": "#E6A925",
  //...rest of colors
}
```

and then see if there is a match:

```js
const colorsList = Object.keys(colorsDict)
const fieldVal = thing.val()
const isColorFound = colorsList.includes(fieldVal) // check for match 

if(isColorFound){
  // update color
  const newColor = colorsDict[fieldVal]
  $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', newColor);
} else {
  // use default
  $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', 'transparent');
}
```

another option could be...

```js
const fieldVal = thing.val()
if(colorsDict[fieldVal]){
  // update color
  const newColor = colorsDict[fieldVal]
  $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', newColor);
} else {
  // use default
  $('.woocommerce-product-gallery figure').css('background-color', 'transparent');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: thing

Line: `const fieldVal = thing.val()`

I cannot figure out what 'thing' is supposed to be in the line: `const fieldVal = thing.val()`.

I tried #pa_color-631, #pa_color, color, input.variation_id, .variation_id. But nothing makes the background color display.

Does the word 'thing' have a special meaning? Or is it supposed to be replaced with something?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34225079)

Comment: Thanks for your help @peska. I'll ask a new question.